# Strange case of "such as seldom"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, books

Excerpt from the [book](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Rq_MCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT54&lpg=PT54&dq=%22the%20cheers%20with%20which%20he%20was%20received%20were%20such%22&source=bl&ots=0s7hZqrPMa&sig=ACfU3U0xkDrmdJgdkK_Mg3jFIoUocjBiSg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwingf-mmMHtAhXQ-yoKHQlxDqAQ6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22the%20cheers%20with%20which%20he%20was%20received%20were%20such%22&f=false) about Paul Morphy and his visit to Birmingham:

> The cheers with which he was received were such as seldom came from others than Englishmen.

I'm having a hard time understanding what it actually means. Only Englishmen have the habit of cheering someone the way they cheered Morphy?

And doesn't the grammatical structure of *the cheers were came* seem a little strange?

Comment: The grammar is not *the cheers were came*. It's *the cheers were such*. What it means is *the cheers were the kind of cheers that don't come very often from anybody but Englishmen.*

Comment: You can't distort a sentence and call it distorted. You have dropped the key word *such* that acts as a pronoun of reference "cheers". Simplify to *Cheers seldom came*.

Comment: The part of the sentence that worries you seems fine to me. But it seems to this native speaker that the expression *other than* ceases to work properly when someone adds an *s* to the *other* and thus turns it into a pronoun.

Comment: "Seldom" is in this case an adverb modifying "came".

Answer (score 1):

The cheers with which he was received were such (**= like those/of a type**) as [**those which**] seldom came from others (**= other nationalities**) than Englishmen.

The cheers with which he was received were of a type which rarely come from anyone but Englishmen.

Answer (score 0):

I think your understanding of the sentence is correct, but the grammar is not. Simplifying your sentence might help:

> The cheers with which he was received were such as ***this**.*

where "this" replaces "seldom came from others than Englishmen".
The information the last part of the sentence brings could be expressed in a separate sentence like this:

> Seldom such cheers came from others than Englishmen.